# Convert from get response to array of type

Tags: functional-programming, typescript, angular-2+, rxjs

I would like to know if this is the best/most efficient/industry standard way of converting from the `http` response to an array of typed values:

Type class:

```
export class University {
  public "state-province": string;
  public country: string;
  public name: string;

  constructor(state_province: string, country: string, name: string) {
    this["state-province"] = state_province;
    this.country = country;
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

Here is the `http` request and conversion. The code in question is within the `map(...)` call:

```
const resp = this.http
  .get<University[]>(`http://universities.hipolabs.com/search?country=United+Kingdom&name=camb`)
  .pipe(map(respData => {
    const uniArr: University[] = [];
    respData.forEach(element => {
      uniArr.push(new University(element['state-province'], element.country, element.name));
    });
    return uniArr;
  }))
  .subscribe(respData => {
    console.log('Content:', respData);
  });
```

In `C#` there are many easier ways to convert the response data of the `get` request into an array (or list) of typed instances. Am I doing this correctly here, in Angular/RxJS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Addressing Your Main Question

> I would like to know if this is the best/most efficient/industry standard way of converting from the http response to an array of typed values

Just as an array has its `forEach()` method it also has a [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method. That method essentially pushes the return value of the callback function into an array and returns the array. Because of this the code within the `map` function callback can be simplified using that method instead of calling the `forEach()` method.

Thus this inner block:

> ```
> .pipe(map(respData => {
>   const uniArr: University[] = [];
>   respData.forEach(element => {
>     uniArr.push(new University(element['state-province'], element.country, element.name));
>   });
>   return uniArr;
> })
> ```

can be simplified to:

```
.pipe(map(respData => {
  return respData.map(element => {
    return new University(element['state-province'], element.country, element.name);
  });
})
```

Notice there is no need to declare the array- i.e. `uniArr` because the `map` method returns an array.

And that can be simplified because there is only a single statement being returned

```
.pipe(map(respData => {
  return respData.map(
    element => new University(element['state-province'], element.country, element.name)
  );
})
```

And the `return` before the call to the `map` method could also be removed though it might make for a long line that some would split

```
.pipe(map(respData => respData.map(element => new University(
  element['state-province'],
  element.country,
  element.name
))))
```

Using the `map` method approach there are no side-effects of the callback function and thus it is a [pure function](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-a-pure-function-in-javascript-acb887375dfe/). This means it is simpler to test, and allows for fewer indentation levels.

[image: 1]

## Review

While there isn't much code to review here, the present code appears quite readable. Indentation is consistent and variables have acceptable names.

It would be wise to check `respData` to ensure it is an array before calling a method like `forEach()` or `map()` on it, and if the code doesn't already catch exceptions from the call to `this.http.get()` then it would be wise to also handle those cases. For example, what happens if the network fails or the API is not available?

Comment: Condensed to the max! I like it